# Shadows won't show on tilted objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

Ok, I have a world space canvas set up with objects tilted towards the camera. Im trying to make hard shadows with the objects on their platforms, however no matter where I place my directional light (it has shadows enabled), I get no shadows:

[image]

There are shadows in the rest of my game, and my quality settings are:

[image]

How can I solve this or fake it if shadows dont work here?

Comment: Is the object a mesh constructed from code or not?

Comment: No. its not they're just objects